# Summarize coefficients and degrees of freedom for logistic regression

Tags: r, formatting

Please see the code below to fit logistic regression model:

```
data = filter(msleep,vore =='carni' | vore == 'herbi')
data$vore = ifelse(data$vore == 'carni',0,1)
up1 =glm(formula = vore~sleep_total, data,family=binomial())
up2 <- round((summary(up1)$coefficients),4)
up2[ , 1]
```

Output gives only coefficients:

```
(Intercept) sleep_total 
    0.9112      -0.0392
```

Output desired (coefficients and degrees of freedom):

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)  sleep_total  
     0.9112      -0.0392  
Degrees of Freedom: 50 Total (i.e. Null);  49 Residual
Null Deviance:      67.35 
Residual Deviance: 66.95    AIC: 70.95
```

Comment: `help("capture.output")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `capture.output` as indicated by Roland in comment. The function is capturing output of a function and store it in a character vector. Then you can choose  lines which are of interest to you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data <- filter(msleep,vore =='carni' | vore == 'herbi')
data$vore <- ifelse(data$vore == 'carni', 0, 1)
up1 <- glm(formula = vore ~ sleep_total, data,family = binomial())
out <- capture.output(summary(up1))
cat(paste0(out[c(9:12, 16:18)], "\n"))
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
 (Intercept)  0.91118    0.68692   1.326    0.185
 sleep_total -0.03920    0.06187  -0.634    0.526
     Null deviance: 67.350  on 50  degrees of freedom
 Residual deviance: 66.945  on 49  degrees of freedom
 AIC: 70.945
```